# Executing npm script(gulp) which is located inside a folder

Tags: npm, gulp, npm-scripts

I have the following structure:

```
main folder
 - src 
 - node modules
 - gulpfiles.js
 - package.json
```

In package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "tasks": "gulp tasks",
```

It works, but if I change the structure to:

```
main folder
 - src 
 - node modules
 - gulp
    - gulpfiles.js
    - gulp.config.js
 - package.json
```

In package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "tasks": "gulp/gulp tasks", or "tasks": "gulp tasks",
```

it gives me the error 'no gulpfile found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize gulp's [`--gulpfile`](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/CLI.md#flags) flag to specify the location of your *gulpfile.js*.

For instance configure your `tasks` script in *package.json* as follows:

```json
"scripts": {
  "tasks": "gulp --gulpfile gulp/gulpfile.js tasks"
},
```